# How to save/retrieve mt19937 so that the sequence is repeated?

Tags: c++, file, random, binaryfiles, mt19937

Here is my attempt

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mt19937 mt(time(0));

    cout << mt() << endl;
    cout << "----" << endl;

    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("/path/save", ios_base::app | ifstream::binary);
    ofs << mt;
    ofs.close();

    cout << mt() << endl;
    cout << "----" << endl;

    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("/path/save", ios::in | ifstream::binary);
    ifs >> mt;
    ifs.close();

    cout << mt() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a possible output

```
1442642936
----
1503923883
----
3268552048
```

I expected the two last number to be the same. Obviously, I have failed to write and/or read my mt19937. Can you help fixing this code?

Comment: Are you sure you succeeded in writing/reading to/from the file? You didn't check for success. It could be that since you never close `ofs` you failed to open `ifs`.

Comment: Ouch.... I edited the code. The problem remained. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your file for writing, you're appending to an existing file.  When you read it back in, you read from the start.

Assuming you don't want to keep the existing content, change the open call to

```
ofs.open("/path/save", ios_base::trunc | ifstream::binary);
```

Using the `trunc` flag instead of `app` will truncate the existing file, so when you reopen it you're reading in the data you just wrote and not old data that was already there.

Comment: The problem was indeed unrelated to handling mt19937 objects. Thanks a lot.